# ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID return nil

Tags: ios, iphone, abaddressbook

My app stores the AddressBook recordIds of Contacts with the same name and later tries to present the addresses to the user to select the desired person. However, when I use the stored recordIds with ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID, it returns nil.
The code below represents the code project - I have "copied" the code that later tries to retrieve the Contact immediately below the code that stores the recordIds.

```
NSString *full = person.compositeName;
                CFArrayRef contacts = ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook, (__bridge        CFStringRef)(full));
                CFIndex nPeople = CFArrayGetCount(contacts);
                if (nPeople)
                {
                    NSMutableArray *rIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                    int numberOfContactsMatchingName = (int)CFArrayGetCount(contacts);
                    if (numberOfContactsMatchingName>1)
                    {
                        for ( int i=0; i<numberOfContactsMatchingName; ++i)
                        {

                            ABRecordID thisId = ABRecordGetRecordID(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(contacts, i));
                            NSNumber *rid = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:thisId];
                            FLOG(@"%d Matched, this ID = %@", numberOfContactsMatchingName, rid);
                            [rIds addObject:rid];
                        }


                        for (int i=0; i<rIds.count; ++i)
                        {
                            //contactRecord = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, (ABRecordID)recId);
                            ABRecordRef contactRecord;
                            contactRecord = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, rIds[i]);
                            if (contactRecord)
                            {

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                FLOG (@"Noone found with recordId %@", rIds[i]);
                            }
                        }
```

So, for example, I just ran this, and it found two Contacts in the address book with the same name - with ids 143 and 305, but when I then tried ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID with ids 143 and 305, both returned nil.
What have I got wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID expects the recordID to be an integer, whereas your code appears to be passing it an NSNumber object.

Try this;

```
contactRecord = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, [rIds[i] integerValue]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Of course - stupid of me. I wonder if the compiler could have warned about it, but I suppose it will just use the address of the NSNumber and treat it as an int. Thanks for your help.